# Wordpress Query showing multiple titles

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query

I have written a query to display in a jquery slider (nivo) however it appears that it is showing all the posts and not just one at a time

This is my code:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-projects">
    <div id="slider2" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=2' ); ?>
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?> 
       <?php endwhile;?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise? The website address is http://www.gordonlundie.com/Howe/

thanks

EDIT ok i found a previous post where i was having a same issue yet its still doing the same :S

```
<div id="recentprojects1">      
     <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('recentprojects1-sidebar') ) :                       endif; ?>
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-projects">
            <div id="slider2" class="nivoSlider">
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();?>

                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Guidance on how i have gone wrong, so that i may not make this mistake in the future is greatly received rather than unhelpful comments.

Comment: This is really a jQuery related question.

Comment: @wyck why is this? as it is showing the post title of both posts and not just one as i want in the query to show!?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have same images in both post.

Comment: Please explain how you came to this conclusion and how to correct the issue.

Comment: Below is the code I can see in direbug:
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.gordonlundie.com/Howe/wp-content/themes/Howe/images/bathroompic.png" style="width: 875px; visibility: hidden; display: inline;">
    <img class="nivo-main-image" src="http://www.gordonlundie.com/Howe/wp-content/themes/Howe/images/bathroompic.png" style="display: inline; width: 875px; height: 428px;">
    <div class="nivo-caption"></div>
    <div class="nivo-directionNav"></div>
</div>